# An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments. ts(2499)

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I am trying to create a new extended `interface` for `express.RequestHandler` but this error seems to come up. I cannot understand why.

```
An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments. ts(2499)
```

The `express.RequestHandler` interface does not support async functions. It says

```
The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>>'?ts(1064)
```

Here are my interfaces

```
export interface IRequest extends express.Request {
    user: IUser;
}

export interface IRequestHandler extends RequestHandler = (
    req: IRequest,
    res: express.Response,
    next: express.NextFunction
) => void | Promise<void>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to extend the `express.Request` interface.

Try:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

interface IUser {
  name: string;
}

declare module 'express' {
  interface Request {
    user: IUser;
  }
}

const controller = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log(req.user);
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly fine. Your help was very much appreciated.